# Declare an object that implements an interface without explicitly using a specific class

Tags: java

Assume I have

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void aMethod();
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void aMethod() {
        Log.d("aMethod");
    }
}
```

And I want to declare an object that implements MyInterface, so I can instantiate it in the constructor as follows

```
public class AnotherClass { 
    Class <? extends MyInterface> mObjectThatImplements;

    public AnotherClass() {
        // Says it cannot convert MyClass to Class <? extends MyInterface>
        mObjectThatImplements = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just change the declaration type. Make it as a Interface, and you can assign any implementation to it.

```
public class AnotherClass { 
    MyInterface mObjectThatImplements;

    public AnotherClass() {           
        mObjectThatImplements = new MyClass();
    }
}
```